I failed to upgrade my dart version to 3.3.4, how do you upgrade this version?
I have a problem with my flutter application, my senior developer can run the app on his device, but when I try to run the application using my device, it doesn't work..
I tried downgrading the flutter version, it still doesn't work. Upgrading, also doesn't work. error line said that I need to have a minimum of 3.3.4 dart version.. but whenever i tried doing so, it still doesn't work

I need to get a minimum of 3.3.4 dart version, anyone knows how to do it?

you can update the Dart version by updating the Flutter version using the below command, it'll update to the latest version available on the channel you have configured, by default it'll be using the stable channel.
flutter upgrade --force


i cannot upgrade the flutter version, i just need to upgrade the dart version, since it's compatible to use the flutter version 3.19.5 and it isn't compatible with the new flutter version... and also i tried what u said, but I still got an error saying Error (Xcode): lib/utilities/styles/theme.dart:10:3: Error: No named parameter with the name 'errorColor'.
